# Unable to get Data from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unity-game-engine

I have an online database on my server, where each username is assigned a primary key id. I want to get this id from the table with the help of PHP. The code is as follows: 
`

```
<?php
   $servername = "uk9.siteground.eu";
   $username = "****";
   $password = "****";
   $dbname = "****";
   $tablename = "Account";
   $user = $_REQUEST["LoggedInUser"];
   // Create connection
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }
   $sql = "SELECT id
           FROM $tablename
           WHERE 'username' LIKE '$user'";

   $result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_object()->id;
   echo $result;
   mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

`

The PHP script works when I use it through my browser, where it prints the correct id number. However, when I call this PHP through Unity:
`

```
public string username;
public string userID;

private void Start()
{
    username = "example";
    StartCoroutine(GetUID());
}

IEnumerator GetUID()
{
    string url = "****";
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("LoggedInUser", username);
    WWW wwwResponse = new WWW(url, form);
    Debug.Log("Connecting to PHP");
    yield return wwwResponse;
    if (wwwResponse.error != null)
    Debug.Log(wwwResponse.error);
    else
    Debug.Log("No Error" + wwwResponse.text);
    userID = wwwResponse.text;
    Debug.Log(userID);
}
```

`
The code reaches the point "Connecting to PHP", but does not print anything after that in the console.

Can anyone help me out with this issue? Thanks

Comment: Please paste properly formatted code here.

Comment: have you checked that the site is working properly? uk9.siteground.eu?

Comment: @MGDroid The site is running ok, since I am able to create and modify tables through Unity. Also all the PHP scripts seem to work both ways.

Comment: @JDSchenck No solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure it's stuck at ""Connecting to PHP""? Is this a local server running on your network?

Comment: No, it is an online server. It does not print any of the other Debug statements. Could it be because of server permissions?

Comment: No. Can you post screenshot of your Console tab after you run this code?

Comment: This is what I see in the Console: https://imgur.com/zDGkn1Q

Comment: Ok can you post the url. I want to try and see what happens.

Comment: I fixed it. I turns out the statement order for yield return was wrong. I made the changes as suggested in the answer below, and also had to modify another script elsewhere. Thanks for your help @Programmer !

Comment: Ok. You can accept his answer if your issue is fixed. By the way his answer does not make sense and I don't think whatever he had there is the issue but if your problem is fixed then congratulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move

```
yield return wwwResponse;
```

to the bottom of your code.

Example:

```
IEnumerator GetUID() {

    string url = "****";
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("LoggedInUser", username);
    WWW wwwResponse = new WWW(url, form);

    //wait till backend responses your request
    while(!wwwResponse.isDone) {
        yield return null; //skip frame
    }

    // keep going when you got your response 
    if(wwwResponse.error != null) {
        Debug.Log(wwwResponse.error);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("No Error" + wwwResponse.text);
        userID = wwwResponse.text;
        Debug.Log(userID);
    }

    yield return wwwResponse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made the changes you asked me to. But it still gets stuck at the same point. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: I found that I had another dependent function elsewhere, which was causing the error. Once I fixed that, the code you suggested also worked. Thanks!